# Trying to get property ' ' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-blade, livewire, laragon

Tengo el siguiente detalle o problema, tengo una tabla en un blade donde le envio algunos datos de solicitud a diferentes usuarios como se muestra en la tabla de base de datos, esta tabla se va actualizando cada segundo automáticamente, pasa un cierto tiempo me muestra el error: "Trying to get property 'intruccion_number' of non-object " y no entiendo por que me lo arroja, no afecta en el funcionamiento simplemente el error me los muestra en un mensaje o etiqueta enzima de mi vista.

Datos de la tabla de BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que este código lo estoy usando en livewire
blade:

```
   <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="secretaria">
      <thead class="table-info">
        <tr>
          <th>Instrucción</th>
          <th>Estatus</th>
          <th>Fecha de respuesta</th>
          <th>¿Que secretaria recibe?</th>
          <th>¿De que secretaria viene?</th>
          <th>Folio</th>
          <th>Fecha de creación de la solicitud</th>
          <th>Posible Respuesta</th>
          <th>Archivo</th>
          <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($procesos as $pro)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$pro->intruccion_number}}</td>
          <td>{{$pro->status}}</td>
          <td>{{$pro->tiempo}}</td>
          <td>{{$pro->nameSecre}}</td>
          @if($pro->status == 'Rechazada')
          <td>{{$pro->secre}}</td>
          @else
          <td>{{$pro->name}}</td>
          @endif
          <td>{{$pro->Folio}}</td>
          <td>{{$pro->Fecha_recibido}}</td>
          <td>{{$pro->respuesta}}</td>
          <td>
            @if ($pro->file == null)
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> --><strong class="text-danger">'Sin archivo'</strong>
            @else
            <a  href="{{route('view.document.solucion',[$pro->Folio, $pro->id_secretaria])}}" class="text" target="_blank" class=""><i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x"></i> Oficio de respuesta</a>
            @endif
            <br><br>
            <a  href="{{route('view.document.peticion',[$pro->Folio, $pro->id_secretaria])}}" class="text-info" target="_blank" class=""><i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-1x"> Petición ciudadana</i></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            @if ($pro->sig_enlace == 1)
            <strong class="texto">'Folio turnado'</strong>
            @elseif($pro->sig_enlace == 2)
            <a href="{{route('dependencias_turnadas', [$pro->id, $pro->Folio])}}" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right btn btn-warning" role="button"> Continuidad Turnado</a>
            @elseif ($pro->status == 'Concluido' && $pro->sig_enlace == 0)
            <a href="{{route('dependencias_turnadas', [$pro->id, $pro->Folio])}}" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right btn btn-warning" role="button"> Siguiente Turnado</a>
            @endif

            @if ($pro->status == 'Nueva')
            <a  class="fa fa-folder-open btn btn-light" style="background-color:#DC143C; color:white" role="button" wire:click="selectData('{{$pro->Folio}}')"  onclick="pulsar('{{$pro->id}}', '{{$pro->Folio}}','{{$pro->intruccion_number}}')"> Nueva petición</a>
            @endif

            @if ($pro->status == 'Aceptada')
              <a href="{{route('solicitud_procesos.show',$pro->id)}}" style="background-color:#008B8B; color:white" class="fa fa-paper-plane btn btn-success" role="button"> Respuesta</a>
            @endif

            @if ($pro->status == 'Finalizado' )
            <strong class="parrafo">'Gracias por su colaboración'</strong><br>
            @endif

            @if ($pro->status != 'Rechazada')
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
            @elseif($pro->id_siguiente == 'true' && $pro->status == 'Rechazada')
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> --><strong>'Gracias por responder'</strong>
            @else
            <a href="{{route('dependencias_turnadas', [$pro->id, $pro->Folio])}}" class="fa fa-window-close btn btn-danger" role="button"> Siguiente Turnado</a>
            @endif

            @if ($pro->status == 'En proceso' )
            <a href="{{route('solicitud_procesos.show',$pro->id)}}" style="background-color:#FF8C00" class="fa fa-paper-plane btn btn-light" role="button"> Continuidad de solución</a>
            @endif
            <!-- <a href="{{route('direccion_turnadas', [$pro->id, $pro->Folio])}}" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right btn btn-warning" role="button"> Turnar dirección</a> -->
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
   use Livewire\Component;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use DB;
   use App\Models\secretaria;
   use App\Models\dependencias_turnadas;
   use App\Models\Solicitudes;
   use Carbon\Carbon;
   use App\Models\User;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
   use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
   Use Illuminate\Support\file;

   class Principal extends Component
   {

     protected $listeners = [
'inicio',
'eventUpdateSolicitud' => 'updateSolicitud',
'eventAceptedSolicitud' => 'aceptSolicitud',
'show',
];

public $Folio,$remitente,$fecha,$asunto,$prioridad,$telefono,$Num_Expe; //ocupa tambien la pagina maestra que es layouts/app


public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.table-turnar.principal')->extends('administration.layouts.app')
->section('content');
    return redirect()->route('solicitud_procesos')->with('solicitudturnada',' Solicitud Turnada');
}



public function inicio(){ //funcion normal de un controlador
  $this->procesos = DB::table('dependencias_turnadas')
    ->leftJoin('secretarias', 'dependencias_turnadas.fk_secretaria', '=','secretarias.id')
    ->leftJoin('solicitudes', 'dependencias_turnadas.fk_solicitud', '=','solicitudes.id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'dependencias_turnadas.remitente', '=', 'users.id')
    ->leftJoin('secretarias as secre', 'dependencias_turnadas.nameSecretaria', '=', 'secre.id')
    ->select('dependencias_turnadas.id','dependencias_turnadas.intruccion_number','dependencias_turnadas.status','solicitudes.Fecha_recibido',
    'dependencias_turnadas.tiempo','dependencias_turnadas.respuesta','dependencias_turnadas.Pasos','users.name','secre.nameSecre as secre',
    'dependencias_turnadas.id_siguiente','secretarias.id as id_secretaria','secretarias.nameSecre','solicitudes.Folio','dependencias_turnadas.file','dependencias_turnadas.sig_enlace')
    ->where('secretarias.id','=',auth()->user()->fk_secretaria)
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
    // dd($this->procesos);
    $this->secretaria = Secretaria::all();
    $this->solicitud = solicitudes::all();
    // dd($this->procesos);
}

public function mount(){ //corre la funcion que deseemos
  $this->inicio();
}
```

Model:

```
   class dependencias_turnadas extends Model
  {
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'dependencias_turnadas';
protected $fillable =['intruccion_number','status','tiempo','respuesta','Pasos','id_siguiente','file','remitente','fk_secretaria','fk_solicitud','sig_turnado','sig_enlace','nameSecretaria','created_at','updated_at'];
   }
```

me podrían orientar o resolver sobre este problemas, ya que aun no entiendo por que me sale este error, no se en donde falle o en que me equivoque, les agradecería mucho su apoyo.

Comment: podrias agregar un if o un isset en <td>{{$pro->intruccion_number}}</td>
que te aparece?

Comment: Ya lo intente con un if y el problema aun sigue, lo hice de esta forma @if($pro != null) debajo de mi forearch y antes del tr